# how to display all accounts on google maps

Tags: apex, visualforce

i integrated google maps in salesforce and it works fine. when i select an account it shows me the location.. Now i want to create a new page where all the accounts will be displayed in the same map. I have been trying some codes but still not working for me. I am new in salesforce and apex and i couldn't manage to make it. anyone can help please ? Here is my code

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <!-- Import Necessary Jquery js File and StyleSheets-->
    <apex:includeScript value="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery_BlogForce9_162, 'js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery_BlogForce9_162, 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqPlugin, '/jquery.blockUI.js')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery_BlogForce9_162, 'css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css')}"/>
    <script>
          var map,geocoder,infowindow;
          var latLngs = [];
          $j = jQuery.noConflict();  
          $j(document).ready(function(){
              initialize();
          });

         function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            //initial cordinates for map init
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            //load the map
            map = new google.maps.Map($j('#map')[0], myOptions);
            codeAddress();

         }

         /*This function codes the address using the Billing Address in the Acoount*/
         function codeAddress(){
              //prepare a string for geocoding
              var address = '{!JSENCODE(Account.BillingStreet)},{!JSENCODE(Account.BillingCity)},{!JSENCODE(Account.BillingCountry)},{!JSENCODE(Account.BillingPostalCode)}';
              console.log(address);
              //geocode the address
              geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
                 //if it is a success
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                      var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                      var marker=addMarker(location );
                      //attach info window to the marker
                      attachInfoWindow(marker,results[0]);

                  }
                  else {
                      alert(status);
                  }
              }); 
         }

         /*
         *This method adds a marker to the provided location
         **/
         function addMarker(location) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map
                });
               //set the bounds and initial zoom
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
            map.setZoom(11);
            return marker;
         }

        //this function shows the address of a marker when it is clicked
        function attachInfoWindow(marker,address){

             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                 if(infowindow!=null)
                    {
                        infowindow.close();
                    }
                //HTML formated string that is used to dispaly info window over the map markers currently showing the name and the formated address

                var contentString = '<div class=" ui-state-active ui-corner-top" style="font-size: 1em; padding: 5px;">Name</div>'
               +'<div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="font-size: .9em; padding: 15px;">{!Account.Name}</div>'  
               +'<div class=" ui-state-active ui-corner-top" style="font-size: 1em; padding: 5px;">Address</div>'
               +'<div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="font-size: .9em; padding: 15px;">'+address.formatted_address+'</div>';
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });
                 infowindow.open(map,marker);
             });
        }

    </script>
    <style>
        #map {

            width:100%;
            height:200px; 

            margin-left:1.5%;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="map" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-state-default"></div>
</apex:page>
```

i found this solution in a forum but i didn't know how to implement it in my code

> > You need to loop through all accounts in the page and  add those to javascript object and use that for population of MAP.

```
<apex:repeat
> value="{!accs}" var="acc">
>               <script type="text/javascript">
>                 accs.push(["{!acc.Name}","{!acc.BillingStreet}","{!acc.BillingCity}","{!acc.BillingCountry}",""{!TEXT(acc.Latitude__c)}","{!TEXT(acc.Longitude__c)}","{!acc.Id}"]);
>             </script>
>         </apex:repeat>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should get list of your accounts and create markers in for loop.

To get records you can use controller or [ajax toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples_asynch.htm). Since you have everything at your page, lets try toolkit.

Create function to pull accounts:

```
function getAccounts() {
    sforce.connection.sessionId='{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    var query = "Select Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingCountry ";
        query += "from Account order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 6";
    result = sforce.connection.query(query);
    return result.getArray("records");
}
```

Wrap codeAddress body with for loop and update address initialization:

```
function codeAddress() {

    var addresses = getAccounts();

    for (item in addresses) {
        var address = addresses[item].BillingStreet +','+ addresses[item].BillingCity +',';
            address += addresses[item].BillingCountry;
        //var address = '{!JSENCODE(Account.BillingStreet)},...

        //-//-
        } 
}
```

Comment: why not use JavaScript remoting?